# Throw event in C that Swift can catch

Tags: ios, c, swift

I use a static library with C code that has a static callback method. A pointer to that method is assigned to an variable. Everytime the library calls this function I would need to handle this event with swift as well. A minimal example would be:

```
static void onEventXYZ(int x, int y, struct z);

int anFunction(){
    libraryFile.attribute = &onEventXYZ;
}


//a C callback function
static void onEventXYZ(int x, int y, struct z){
    //function body
}
```

My problem here is that I have no idea how to react to such an callback from within a swift class. It is notable to mention that I also need to react to this callback while the app might be in background.

Is it possible to throw an event or signal that swift is able to catch and handle?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a function that takes pointer to that callback function...

```
void doSomething(void (*callback)(int, int)); // int parameters just for example
```

... it's translated to Swift as follows:

```
func doSomething(callback: @convention(c) (Int, Int) -> Void)
```

This means you can use any function as a callback, as long as it's compatible with `@convention(c)` standard:

```
doSomething {
    print($0)
    print($1)
}

// or

func onSomething(i: Int, j: Int) {
    print(i)
    print(j)
}

doSomething(onSomething)

// or

let onSomething: (Int, Int) -> Void = { i, j in
    print(i)
    print(j)
}

doSomething(onSomething)
```

Comment: Okey, it seems I was not precice enough, I will update the question. I got a pointer on a static function that is assigned to an attribute. And I need to fire swiftcode as well as c code when the library fires a specific event